# A proper way to customize different components from React MUI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to override the whole MUI component, to have more variants and new props.

*React Example component screenshot:*
[image: React Example component screenshot]

The Example is in the picture above. Im looking for a good practice, i didnt have much experience with MUI, is that a good idea to create new theme for every overridden component? Can i use css variables in this theme object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not how MUI is supposed to be used. You should not use many different themes.

As a rule of thumb you should define *one* theme for the whole app, and apart from that just use the predefined MUI styles, and don't use a lot of custom styles.

#### Customizing

It is ok to **customize a few components**, which don't fit into the general theme, but that should be used sparingly, and not be done via different themes, but via custom styles or inline styles.

It is also ok to define **more than one theme**, but that should very rarely be necessary. I'd say you should not do it.

#### Material Design

If you find that you need to customize a lot, you probably should not use MUI at all. [MUI is designed](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/overview/) to use mainly ["material design"](https://m3.material.io/):

> Material UI is an open-source React component library that implements Google's Material Design.

So if you don't want material design, then this is probably the wrong library for you.

#### MUI Base

I just now noticed myself that there is ["MUI Base"](https://mui.com/base/getting-started/overview/), which is supposed to offer the powerful components without styling (so probably not based on "material design" ?). But I don't know "MUI Base" myself yet.

Comment: I'm not sure if im asking a proper question. The end if the day i just want, for example if i have a figma with 10 different styled buttons to have ability to make them via 10 different variants of MUI button, or TextField or any other component.

Comment: ok. It is ok to add multiple variants to _one_ theme. But you should not define 10 different themes _(You said "is that a good idea to create new theme for every overridden component")_. You obviously have already seen the page [how-to-customize](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/.)

Comment: Yep, thank you, that is the reason why i said that im not sure if im ask proper question. It is still confused about making styles in one object. Do y know if i can use css variables in that theme object

Comment: I don't know. But maybe this helps: [experimental-api/css-theme-variables](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/overview/), [usage](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/usage/)